# Capture follow-up HTTP requests when scraping a page with Scrapy or Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

When I **scrape** a page often there are multiple hollow-up HTTP requests triggered by the first GET request, either included objects (images, scripts, stylesheets), or dynamically triggered through javascript (progressively loaded content).

I want to capture these requests, both the request URLs and the responses. Is there a way to do it with Scrapy/Spalsh or Selenium? The solution I'm considering at the moment is to combine Scrapy with Scapy, but I don't want to over-engineer it if there's a simpler way to do it.

Comment: for non-javascript follow-ups and scrapy you can just extract the urls ob included objects and yield new Requests for them within your parse method.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about this solution but I also want to catch dynamic requests, that's why I need something extra.